# Primitive types to AnyRef in Scala

Tags: scala, cassandra, prepared-statement

I am adding new features to an open source project(pillar) to migrate Cassandra tables. I have a problem in operation that insert values a new table.
There is a table in Cassandra:

```
create table customer(
  name text,
  age int,
  point int,
  primary key(name, age)
)
```

I want to migrate from this table to test_person table.

```
create table test_person (
  name text,
  surname text,
  point int,
  city text,
  primary key(name)
)
```

Here is an operation:

```
var s: PreparedStatement = session.prepare("insert into test_person  (name, age, point) values (?, ?, ?)"); 

var r: Row = session.execute("select * from customer").one()

var arr: Array[AnyRef] = new Array[AnyRef](3)

arr(0) = row.getObject("name")

arr(1) = row.getObject("age")

arr(2) = row.getObject("point")



session.execute(s.bind(arr))
```

This is error message:
Type mismatch Can't assign primitive value to object.

I got as object and assign an array typed of AnyRef. What is wrong?

How can I handle this

Comment: Which line throws error?

Comment: arr(1) = row.getObject("age")

arr(2) = row.getObject("point")

Comment: does row.getObject("age") return an object or an int?

Comment: Class name is java.lang.Integer

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because there is an implicit conversion happening from java.lang.Integer to Int. And Int is of type AnyVal not an AnyRef. Try using Array[Any] instead of Array[AnyRef] OR You can disable the implicit conversion by `import scala.Predef.{Integer2int => _}`

```
// This method in Predef.scala is causing the conversion
implicit def Integer2int(x: java.lang.Integer): Int
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because, `AnyRef` is for objects and `AnyVal` is for primitives. You can use an `Array[Any]` in your case:

```
var s: PreparedStatement = session.prepare("insert into test_person  (name, age, point) values (?, ?, ?)");
var r: Row = session.execute("select * from customer").one()
val arr = Array(r.getString("name"), r.getInt("age"), r.getInt("point"))
```

Comment: It works but I don't want to  know how many columns there are in tables. Can I do it a loop in Array(..) ?

Comment: You can use ArrayBuffer of type Any. Then you can keep adding more entries.